# How to Create Razor Control '@Html.Partial("")' Dynamically or Runtime using JQuery document.createElement() in MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to dynamically create a div and a `Partial View` in  MVC application.
HTML controls are getting created easily by using `createElement()` but RAZOR controls are not. 
Is it possible to create RAZOR controls dynamically using JQuery `createElement()` method ?
What should be the best solution.

```
            contentType: "application/json",
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("SecondGrid")',
            data: JSON.stringify({ intSerializeDataId: intSerializeDataId }),                datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                var lastDiv = document.getElementById("divLast");

                var isDiv = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
                isDiv = isDiv.length - 5;

                if (isDiv == 0) {

                    var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
                    iDiv.id = '1';
                    document.getElementById('dynamicGridDiv').appendChild(iDiv);     

             //Here is the Problem.-----------------------------------------------------------------                   
                    var innerDiv = document.createElement('@Html.Partial("_Passinggrid", new List<KanakaTypeLib.UXTypeLib.MasterPassingGrid>())');      // Here is the Problem
                    innerDiv.id = '1'+ '_PartialView';
                    iDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);
                    document.body.appendChild(iDiv);

                    document.getElementById("1").html(data);
                    headerConstant();
                    headerConstant1();
                }
                else {
                    var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
                    iDiv.id = Number(isDiv) + 1;
                    document.getElementById('dynamicGridDiv').appendChild(iDiv);        

                    var innerDiv = document.createElement();
                    innerDiv.id = (Number(isDiv) + 1) + '_PartialView';
                    iDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);
                    document.body.appendChild(iDiv);

                    document.getElementById(iDiv.id).html(data);
                    headerConstant();
                    headerConstant1();
                }
                lastDiv.before(iDiv);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("in ERROR");
                $('#SecondPassingGrid').html(data);
                //                            headerConstant();
                headerConstant1();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Short answer is NO.

Comment: Jquery/Javascript lives on the client side, Razor on the server side... this *can't* work. You should probably take a deeper look at the pipeline of an ASP.NET MVC web application.

Comment: but we create razor controls on client side or on VIEW only...so it should be work as client side code. @Robert

Comment: Razor gets rendered on the server, only the resulting output is delivered to the client.